# How to extract href links within a page tree with Selenium using Python?

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, web

Trying to get the "field" links nested in the page tree on this page. I can get as far as retrieving the first level links, but not any of the third level links that require clicking and expanding the tree, I think because that's dynamically generated? I've tried the XPATH for the inner elements in the page tree as well, but got back nothing. Here's the code I'm using so far. I think I need to include some additional code to click and expand the tree? Do I need to use other libraries? Very thankful for any help

Code

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument("--headless=new")

driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)

url = 'https://ddwiki.reso.org/display/DDW17/'
driver.get(url)

elem = driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, "plugin_pagetree_children_list")

links=elem.find_elements(By.TAG_NAME, "a")

for lnk in links:
   print(lnk.get_attribute('href'))

driver.quit()
```

Output (shortened)

```
https://ddwiki.reso.org/display/DDW17/Data+Dictionary+v1.7+Introduction?src=contextnavpagetreemode

https://ddwiki.reso.org/display/DDW17/Property+Resource?src=contextnavpagetreemode

https://ddwiki.reso.org/display/DDW17/Member+Resource?src=contextnavpagetreemode

https://ddwiki.reso.org/display/DDW17/Office+Resource?src=contextnavpagetreemode

https://ddwiki.reso.org/display/DDW17/Contacts+Resource?src=contextnavpagetreemode
```

HTML

```
<div class="plugin_pagetree_children" id="children393239-0">
    <ul class="plugin_pagetree_children_list" id="child_ul393239-0">
       <li>
          <div class="plugin_pagetree_childtoggle_container">
             <a id="plusminus393267-0" class="plugin_pagetree_childtoggle aui-icon aui-icon-small aui-iconfont-chevron-right" href="" data-type="toggle" data-page-id="393267" data-tree-id="0" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Expand item Data Dictionary v1.7 Introduction">
             </a>
          </div>
          <div class="plugin_pagetree_children_content">
             <span class="plugin_pagetree_children_span" id="childrenspan393267-0">                        <a href="/display/DDW17/Data+Dictionary+v1.7+Introduction?src=contextnavpagetreemode">Data Dictionary v1.7 Introduction</a>
             </span>
          </div>
          <div id="children393267-0" class="plugin_pagetree_children_container">
          </div>
       </li>
       <li>
          <div class="plugin_pagetree_childtoggle_container">
             <a id="plusminus393372-0" class="plugin_pagetree_childtoggle aui-icon aui-icon-small aui-iconfont-chevron-down" href="" data-type="toggle" data-page-id="393372" data-tree-id="0" aria-expanded="true" aria-label="Expand item Property Resource" data-children-loaded="true" data-expanded="true">
             </a>
          </div>
          <div class="plugin_pagetree_children_content">
             <span class="plugin_pagetree_children_span" id="childrenspan393372-0">                        <a href="/display/DDW17/Property+Resource?src=contextnavpagetreemode">Property Resource</a>
             </span>
          </div>
          <div id="children393372-0" class="plugin_pagetree_children_container">
             <ul class="plugin_pagetree_children_list" id="child_ul393372-0">
                <li>
                   <div class="plugin_pagetree_childtoggle_container">
                      <a id="plusminus393402-0" class="plugin_pagetree_childtoggle aui-icon aui-icon-small aui-iconfont-chevron-down" href="" data-type="toggle" data-page-id="393402" data-tree-id="0" aria-expanded="true" aria-label="Expand item Business Group" data-children-loaded="true" data-expanded="true">
                      </a>
                   </div>
                   <div class="plugin_pagetree_children_content">
                      <span class="plugin_pagetree_children_span" id="childrenspan393402-0">                        <a href="/display/DDW17/Business+Group?src=contextnavpagetreemode">Business Group</a>
                      </span>
                   </div>
                   <div id="children393402-0" class="plugin_pagetree_children_container" style="display: block;">
                      <ul class="plugin_pagetree_children_list" id="child_ul393402-0">
                         <li>
                            <div class="plugin_pagetree_childtoggle_container">
                               <span class="no-children icon"></span>
                            </div>
                            <div class="plugin_pagetree_children_content">
                               <span class="plugin_pagetree_children_span" id="childrenspan393855-0">                        <a href="/display/DDW17/BusinessName+Field?src=contextnavpagetreemode">BusinessName Field</a>
                               </span>
                            </div>
                            <div id="children393855-0" class="plugin_pagetree_children_container">
                            </div>
                         </li>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your site has structure, when inner level toggles are rendered only after click on parent level toggle.

To get all links of toggles you need to create loop, where you're:

1. Store amount of links
2. Click on toggle
3. Wait until links amount are not the same (child toggle level is rendered)
4. Re-init toggles array
5. Increment iteration

When index would be out of bounds, the would be meant that no new toggle is appeared after opening the last one.

Toggles can be located by css selector `a[data-tree-id]`.

So, your code should be:

```py
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument("--headless=new")

driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 20)

def get_links_len():
    return len(driver.find_elements(By.TAG_NAME, "a"))

def wait_for_values_not_equal(value_func, value, timeout=10, interval=0.5):
    start_time = time.time()

    while value_func() == value:
        if time.time() - start_time > timeout:
            raise TimeoutError("Timeout: Value did not change within the specified time.")
        time.sleep(interval)

    return value_func() != value

driver.get("https://ddwiki.reso.org/display/DDW17/")
elem = driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, "plugin_pagetree_children_list")
wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "a[data-tree-id]")))

toggles = elem.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "a[data-tree-id]")
temp_links_len = 0
iteration = 0
while True:
    try:
        temp_links_len = get_links_len()
        toggles[iteration].click()
        wait_for_values_not_equal(get_links_len, temp_links_len)
        toggles = elem.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "a[data-tree-id]")
        iteration += 1
    except IndexError:
        break

links = elem.find_elements(By.TAG_NAME, 'a')

for lnk in links:
    href = lnk.get_attribute('href')
    if href:
        print(href)
```

Comment: this was great! thanks so much for the guidance

Answer (score 0):

Yes, its dynamically generated.
Maybe you could try clicking all of the dropdown icons before continuing.

```
dropdowns = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, "//a[contains(@aria-label,'Expand item')]")
for dropdown in dropdowns:
   dropdown.click()
   time.sleep(2)
```